# Biblatex citations don't go away even after removing all references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, sorting

That, and the order of the citations persists even if I write `sorting=none`.

I am using [this template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), which uses Biblatex. I have the following command in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex,style=phys,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

Writing `sorting=none` makes no difference. If I delete all instances of e.g. reference #22, the printed bibliography at the end still shows that reference, even after compiling twice. Also if I cite it at the beginning, instead of changing to #1 it remains forever #22.

Other bibliography related commands that I am using are:

```
\addbibresource{my_bibfile.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

(I think that is all of them) How can I fix this so references are in order and forgotten if I remove all instances?

Comment: you need to re-run biber to regenerate the bibliography

Comment: As David Carlisle says: It is not enough to (re)run LaTeX if you change which entries you cite or if you change something significant about your setting (sort order etc.). You also need to rerun the bibliography tool (BibTeX or Biber; generally Biber is used with `biblatex`, but you explicitly requested to use BibTeX) as well. There should be messages about that in the `.log` file. Never ignore errors or warnings in the `.log` file. (That's not quite true: You can decide to ignore some warnings, but you should read them first and try to understand why they are there.)

Comment: ah sorry I didn't notice the `backend=bibtex`  so rerun bibtex not biber

Comment: I reran `biber` and solved my issue. Thanks! Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typesetting of citations and the bibliography with `biblatex` (and BibTeX) does not only involve running LaTeX, it also involves a bibliography tool (Biber or BibTeX). See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for a wonderful explanation of the process.

Hence, it is not enough to (re)run LaTeX if you change which entries you cite or if you change something significant about your bibliography/citation settings (style, sort order etc.). You need to rerun the bibliography tool as well.

There should be messages about that in the .log file along the lines of

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                myfilename
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Never ignore errors or warnings in the .log file. (OK: You can *decide to* ignore some warnings, but you should read them first and try to understand why they are there.)

---

Your document should show as intended if you run LaTeX, Biber/BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX.